# Insert a swing custom form into another custom form

Tags: java, swing

I've created 2 custom forms with netbeans GUI builder:

- the 1st one is a JPanel with several JPanel and components in it and an empty JPanel (JPanel1) in the middle.
- the 2nd is a JPanel Form with some components in it (jbutton,etc...).

What I'd like to do is to insert the 1st form into a JFrame (that I succeed) and then everytime I click a button on the first form it inserts the second form into the empty JPanel of the first form. I failed on this second part.

I won't post the entire code here as it is mostly generated by netbeans but here's the `actionperformedevent` on the button of first form and the test JFrame class I wrote:

```
public class TABLE_1 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form TABLE
     */
    public TABLE_1() {
        initComponents();

    }
private void jButton29ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //empty Jpanel of 1st form
        LigneProduit2 p1 = new LigneProduit2(); //p1 is the 2nd form(JPanel)
        jPanel1.add(p1);
}


public class TABLE extends JFrame{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame j1 = new JFrame();
        TABLE_1 t1 = new TABLE_1(); // 1st form
        j1.add(t1);
        j1.pack();
        j1.setVisible(true);
}
```

So yeah, p1 doesn't show up in t1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke validate() on jPanel1, this will layout the panel's components

jPanel1.validate();

Comment: works perfectly thanks a lot ! one more question, if I click more than once how to force it to create a new row?

Comment: you need another layout, check BoxLayout. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: I looked at grid layout, borderlayout, grouplayout but missed the boxLayout,looks perfect, thanks again!